# New to this site, can't ask a 2nd question

Tags: bug

New to this site, but not StackExchange network. I asked [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100924) earlier today. I would like to ask another. But everytime I click the "Ask Question" button from various places on this RPi SE site, I am thrown into editing my first question. Is this because I'm new to the RPi SE?

Answer (score 6):

I solved it. It turns out that somehow while posting the previously asked question (see link above) I somehow still had a saved draft of that question. Clicking "Discard Draft" did the trick.